# Perl file transfer through Net::SFTP::Foreign thows error: password authentication not available

Tags: perl, sftp, file-transfer

I have manually added `Net::SFTP::Foreign` module files(since don't have access to install the perl modules) to my current working directory. My SFTP transfer script shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I/home/vinod/scripts/sftp_test/lib

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

print "Starting the script execution\n";

my ($hostip, $username, $password) = ("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "user", "password");

my $rdir = "/home/shared_dir/Vinod";
my $fullfilename = "/home/vinod/scripts/sftp_test/abc.txt";

my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(host=>$hostip , user=>$username , password=>$password, more=>[qw(-v -o PreferredAuthentications=password)]) or die "Cannot open remote file list connection: $!";

$sftp->setcwd($rdir) or die "unable to change cwd: " . $sftp->error;

$sftp->put("$fullfilename", "$rdir/xyz.txt") or die "put failed: " . $sftp->error;

$sftp->disconnect;

print "Done\n";
```

But this script throws me an error:

```
Starting the script execution
password authentication not available, IO::Pty is not installed or failed to load: Can't locate IO/Pty.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 . /home/vinod/scripts/sftp_test/lib) at /home/vinod/scripts/sftp_test/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign/Backend/Unix.pm line 256.
 at test.pl line 17
```

Whether this error is because of module `IO::Pty` not installed.

When I manually transfer files using `sftp` command it works, but through script its not.

Answer (score 2):

The underlying process (be it sftp of scp or whatever) needs to get the password from the Perl program. The transfer of the password can't break the security, i.e. it must be passed via a pseudo-terminal. That's why [IO::Pty](http://p3rl.org/IO::Pty) is required.

When you run sftp in a terminal, it allocates a pseudo terminal to ask you for the password. That also explains why you can't e.g. send the password to the standard input of the command.

Comment: Since the module `Net::SFTP::Foreign` I have added manually, how I can have `IO::Pty` module hierarchy ? In `metacpan` I could see `Pty.pm` is under `IO-Tty` directory. So can I create a directory `IO-Tty` under `../lib` and follow the hierarchy which is in `IO-Tty`.

Comment: Why don't you use a CPAN client?

Comment: Also, IO::Pty needs a C compiler, as it has an XS component. So you can install it manually in the standard way: `perl Makefile.PL && make && make install`, but that's exactly what a cpan client does.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in the question (now I did) that I don't have access to install the modules. So manually I'm adding all the required module files. As you mentioned about `Makefile.PL` and `install` process I don't think its able to install, let's give me a try. That's why I asked how this module hierarchy should look like.

Comment: [Yes, even you can use CPAN](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=693828)

Comment: `sftp` does not allocate any pseudo-terminal. It just uses the terminal it was started from to interact with the user, which it opens via `/dev/tty`. `ssh` may allocate a pseudo-terminal (when its stdin was a terminal, no explicit command was given, etc), but always on the _remote_ machine, never on the _local_ machine.

Comment: @vinodk89 I haven't used them, but there seem to exist perl interfaces to libssh2 (`Net::SSH2` and `Net::SSH2::SFTP`) which should be more robust than trying to run ssh/sftp in a pseudo-tty.

Comment: @mosvy, Net::SSH2::SFTP is not robust in any way. SFTP support in the underlaying libssh2 is quite buggy. Also, Net::SFTP::Foreign can be used on top of Net::SSH2 but usually this is only recommended on Windows.